# Not able to install ganache; getting and NPM in power shell

Tags: python, npm, solidity, ganache, web3py

I got ran into an error when I ran `npm install ganache --global`.

````
PS C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\Documents\projects\Learning Solidity\Demos> npm install ganache --global npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [ npm WARN cleanup   [ npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules',         npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\bufferutil'] { npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4082, npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EBUSY', npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir', npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\bufferutil' npm WARN cleanup     } npm WARN cleanup   ] npm WARN cleanup ] npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.       npm ERR!   builder.cc npm ERR! C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown\deps\leveldb\port-libuv\port_uv.h(42,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'uv.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown\deps\leveldb\leveldb.vcxproj] npm ERR!   snappy-sinksource.cc npm ERR!   snappy-stubs-internal.cc npm ERR!   snappy.cc npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc npm ERR!   snappy.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown\build\Release\\snappy.lib npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.1.32319.34) found at: npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\leveldown\\build\\config.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.14.0',npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.14.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\leveldown', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\leveldown\\build', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ] npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe     npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ] npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: ``` C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1 ``
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown`  
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1`
`npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`` npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chetachi Ugwu-Ojobe\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-04T12_27_54_751Z-debug-0.log`
````

Has anyone experienced anything similar?